# My animation stops halfway through?

Tags: animation, keyframes, timeline

I'm doing a short little animation for a side project and the length is 167 frames. I think I accidentally clicked something and now it only plays up to half of the clip before looping.

So for example let's say I was doing an animation of someone sitting down. Halfway through this animation, it just cuts off as if it reached the end of the clip already.

Also that green line that runs while the animation is playing is always really far behind my mouse. I'm really stuck and confused by this, so I'd really love some insight on this subject.

Also due to copyright, I can't actually share or upload the file or any of it's contents.

Here are some screenshots of the timeline and settings:
[image: Property of CraftyMaelyss]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having non equal numbers in the "*Time remapping*" fields results in a "warped" time: the timeline frames and the animation frames cease to correspond 1-to-1 to each other.

[image]

If setting these *Time remapping* values to 40 and 100 wasn't intentional, revert their values to 100 and 100.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.blendernation.com/2015/04/25/rendering-your-animation-in-slow-motion/ This should help you understand slow motion/speeding up